# Facebook explicit logout: website vs app

Tags: facebook, logout, policy

From Facebook Policy: "Your website must offer an explicit Log Out option.."

I have an application that runs as iframe inside Facebook. I must provide a Log out link here? (i see no one of apps have).

I am asking to be sure, probably on separate sites must be this Log Out?

Answer (score 1):

Websites like http://www.reverbnation.com will have an explicit log out option.  Iframed apps are not considered websites in their documentation.